# How the Bodhisatta found the way across, vast amount of time, misguided views, by himself?

Tags: buddha, paramitas, parami, bodhisatta

It's said that after the Bodhisatta become Buddha, he was kind of surprised how himself came to that position, across vast amount of time, alternate views, other paths, misleading views. (basically infinite number/amount of spaghetti)

**So, how he did it?**

**What kind of thinking / practice oneself do in order to achieve / make that kind of determination?**

**How oneself find it's way across this vast nonsense?**

**How oneself fight against all odds, yet tell nobody?**

Above all questions may seem different, but they all ask the same basic question. That's why they all are in same stack question.

*I am not making this question up, that's what my heart is asking for few years now.*

Answer (score 1):

> **So, how he did it?**

I think in the Mahayana tradition, it all begins with [a vow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva_vow). According to the tradition, there are many beings who make this vow but many either give up along the way or choose to attain Enlightenment instead of seeing it through to become a Sammasambuddha.

> **What kind of thinking / practice oneself do in order to achieve / make that kind of determination?**

It is the [ten paramitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81ramit%C4%81) although the list differs somewhat in the Theravada and Mahayana tradition. Personally, I find perfecting any of these paramitas an endeavour in self-torture; admirable but insane (sorry for the language).

> **How oneself find its way across this vast nonsense?**

I presume you mean the nonsense as in the seemingly endless cycles of samsara. I think if you read some of the [Jataka tales](https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/jataka-tales-english) about our Buddha (Gautama) in his previous lives as he was perfecting the paramitas, you will realize that there was a lot of meanderings. There were times when he was lost (to greed, aversion or delusion) for a long time in samsara before regaining back the path of practice and making meaningful progress. Often, it seems like it was a process of self-realization that a certain path is a dead-end that caused the would-be Buddha to reverse course. Other times, [a meeting with a Buddha and the opportunity to practice under such an enlightened being](https://suttacentral.net/mn81/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) really speed up the progress. Nonetheless, the amount of time spent perfecting the paramitas is incredible.

> **How oneself fight against all odds, yet tell nobody?**

I don’t think a Bodhisattva do this practice specifically for a particular someone. They don’t have anyone to rely on for guidance (except a rare and chance encounter with a Buddha now and then), not even fellow Bodhisattvas. They have to be a light upon themselves, trying out and learning all kinds of dhammas. It is a trial-and-error process requiring a lot of patience (one of the paramitas).

Personally, I realized as I grow older that it is precisely *this willingness to help others* that forces a person to learn skills and gain understanding in unfamiliar (and often uncomfortable) areas; such that one’s wisdom and skillful abilities are vastly enriched and expanded. Without this innate desire to want to **save all beings** and the insane amount of time to learn and perfect the necessary skills and understandings, a being just cannot reach that level of perfection in wisdom, compassion and skills needed to be a vehicle that guides and help transport other sentient beings across the vast sea of samsara to the safe shore of Nirvana.

> *I am not making this question up, that's what my heart is asking for few years now.*

I thought of this too as I started as a Buddhist in the Mahayana tradition. Understanding the implications made me realize becoming a Buddha is just not in my DNA. But that doesn't mean I will stop actively going out of my way to help others as and when possible. Helping others really do expand our breath of wisdom, courage, patience, compassion and skillfulness....just not as a Bodhisattva.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..  "Without this innate desire to want to save all beings", how someone make something like that? what drives them to keep suffering for others? https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/50425/25614  .

Comment: The Bodhisattva vow is not a simple process. Its beginning could have been simple but subsequently it should be reinforced in the presence of [a Buddha who will then make a formal prophecy](https://dharmanet.org/DellaBodhisattva.htm) (but don't ask me how the first Buddha came about). We all have this innate desire to want to help others, guide them towards a better future. But it is like a flickering flame that goes out at times to be reignited at another time. I think a Bodhisattva's flame is akin to a sun. Perhaps, how it is enlarged to such an extent is the insane part.

Answer (score -1):

There was no "spaghetti", no "infinite views" and no inherent "fight". The Bodhisatta:

1. Simply realised when young his life was impermanent, which caused a loss of intoxication in his youth and sensuality. Refer to [AN 3.38](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.038.than.html).
2. Simply understood sensuality (such as porn) was deadly to the development of wisdom and a peaceful mind. Refer to [MN 19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.019.than.html).
3. Simply examined his mind until he came to understand how suffering arises & ceases. Refer to [SN 12.10](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN12_10.html), where the Bodhisatta came to understand the idea/mental concept of "aging & death" is born from ignorant self-view attachment.

The term 'Bodhisatta' originally simply meant "being seeking enlightenment". The term 'Bodhisatta' originally did not mean countless past & future lives of spaghetti. The Bodhisatta predominately used wisdom or "wise investigation" ("yoniso manasikārā"; "appropriate attention") rather than predominantly "fighting", as [SN 12.10](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN12_10.html) explains.

Comment: please do not delete and repost the same answer to get around downvotes or comments that you don't like.

Comment: Downvotes and negative comments could be a result of bad karma. [This answer and its suggestions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12280/reducing-the-power-of-a-bad-karma/13161#13161) offers constructive ways to address the issue.